# Carrierwave add pictures through "heroku rails console" from s3 on production side

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image-processing, heroku, amazon-s3, carrierwave

I have a simple app that uploads picture that i am saving using carrierwave in blog database.
(having title,body and image) and my credentials are working fine.

I have an image uploaded in s3 account with this url:
/s3.amazonaws.com/Buket_name/..path../thumb_smile.png

How can I update database with image from heroku rails console.
This doesnt seem to work:

```
b = Blog.new
b.title = "a blog"
b.body = "some text"
b.image =  File.new("s3.amazonaws.com/Buket_name/..path../thumb_smile.png","a")
or
b.image =  File.open("s3.amazonaws.com/Buket_name/..path../thumb_smile.png","r")

Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - 
s3.amazonaws.com/Buket_name/..path../thumb_smile.png
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use CarrierWave's [`remote_{name}_url=`](http://carrierwave.rubyforge.org/rdoc/classes/CarrierWave/Mount.html#M000027) attribute for the easiest solution.

```
b = Blog.new
b.title = "a blog"
b.body = "some text"
b.remote_image_url = 'http://s3.amazonaws.com/Buket_name/..path../thumb_smile.png'
b.save
```

This functionality is specific to CarrierWave, so if you are looking to do something similar with another library, use [`open-uri`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/open-uri/rdoc/OpenURI.html) from the standard library.

```
require 'open-uri'
image = open('http://s3.amazonaws.com/Buket_name/..path../thumb_smile.png')
```

Now image is a [`Tempfile`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/tempfile/rdoc/Tempfile.html) that can be used like a file in your Ruby script.

```
require 'open-uri'
image = open('http://s3.amazonaws.com/Buket_name/..path../thumb_smile.png')

b = Blog.new
b.title = "a blog"
b.body = "some text"
b.image = image
b.save
```

Comment: Thanks for carrierwave explanation